# Driver Tool accidently deleted, no netwrok access

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I accidently deleted driver tool from the control panel. Now In device manager, at Network Controller has yellow question mark. There is no wireless icon or wizard under netwrok connection in control panel. I'm not able to enable any network connection neither wireless nor bluetooth. My system's OS is windows XP home. When I copied 'driver tool' exe file for xp home and try to run it throws me error as" This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it. or cont"

Comment: Please read our FAQ before posting again, this question isn't appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Oy, that last attempt might make things a bit harder.

It's no big deal if a `*.CPL` shortcut disappears from the Control Panel. You can still run them manually from the `Run...` menu. However, if I understand correctly, you then overwrote the (working) version.

Now, you might be able to recover through the [Windows File Protection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222193) feature. As administrator, run the `sfc /scanonce` command and restart.